# How to use mat-grid or grid list inside mat-option instead of using css display grid

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular8

I have name and id both displayed in two different lines in mat-option, I am using `display:grid` in mat-option-list css , instead i wanted to use mat-grid or grid-list properties to display them as in grid.

```
<input matInput class="form-control input" [(ngModel)]="userTextvalue"matAutocomplete]="auto">
  <mat-autocomplete class="user-autocomplete" #auto="matAutocomplete">
    <mat-option-list *ngFor="let user of filteredUsers" [value]="user.name">
        <span class="username">{{user.name}}</span>
        <span class="usercode">{{user.code}}</span>
      </mat-option>
  </mat-autocomplete>
```

scss:

```
.mat-option-text {
  line-height: normal;
  display: grid;
}
```

[[image: current behaviour[1]]

Answer (score 1):

why do you not wrap all in a wrapper?

```
   <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option">
        <div class="wrapper">
          <span>{{option}}</span>
          <span>{{option}}</span>
        </div>
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
```

Where your .css is like

```
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}
```

see [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-n74pnz-pgurdc?file=app%2Fautocomplete-simple-example.html)